# How to set Navigation Bar to the bottom of Scaffold?

Tags: android, material-design, android-jetpack-compose

As I separated the `Navigation Bar` code from the `Scaffold` code, I ran into this weird bug where the `Navigation Bar` is always stuck on top

Here's an image:
[image: A screenshot of the bug]

Here's the Scaffold Code:

```
fun MainContainer() {
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = { AppNavigationBar() }
    ) {

    }
}
```

And the Navigation Bar code:

```
fun AppNavigationBar() {
    // Navigation bar composable
    NavigationBar {
        items.forEachIndexed { index, screenItem ->

            NavigationBarItem(
                selected = index == selectedItem,
                onClick = {
                    selectedItem = index
                    navController.navigate(screenItem.route)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it the same when you add any content?

Comment: What version of compose are you on? I don't see `NavigationBar` in `1.1.0-rc01`. What happens if you use `BottomNavigation` and `BottomNavigationItem` instead.

Comment: @Rafsanjani I'm using `1.1.0-rc01` also, but with material design 3 instead

Comment: @Jakoss Yeah you were right. Made a mistake with the content placement. Solved it now, thanks!